# Show traffic in google map using GMap.Net

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I'm using GMap.NET to render google map  in my wpf application and It works fine. but now i want to show the traffic information on the map .
How can i do that in GMap.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Displaying traffic using GMap.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440171/c-displaying-traffic-using-gmap-net)