# Displaying traffic using GMap.NET

Tags: c#, .net, gmap.net

I'm using GMap.NET to render Google Map in my Windows Form application and It works fine. Now I would like to show the traffic information on the map. Is there any way to do that in GMap.NET?

Comment: Do you mean real-time traffic conditions, or simply road maps in conjunction with the satellite imagery?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for but Murat mentioned that you can't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last version, 1.9.2, simply specify this before use control.

```
GoogleMapProvider.Instance.Version = "m,traffic@336000000";
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do that. GMap.Net doesn't support any traffic informations as far as I know. And they didn't any mentions for traffic information in documentation.

[Documentation](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GMap.NET.WindowsForms&referringTitle=Documentation)